# Leadfoot session object returns promises

Tags: javascript, promise, functional-testing, intern, leadfoot

I am attempting to use the leadfoot module for functional testing with the intern and selenium.

For this test, I'm trying to click a button in one place, then check the display property of a element elsewhere on the page.

I couldn't find a way to expand the search of the findById call, so I tried using the session property, which seems to work, but results in everything returning a promise.

The only way I've found that will make it work is by chaining then functions.
What makes the session (and the elements its functions return) different?

```
return this.remote
    .findById('buttonContainer')
    .findByClassName('buttonClass')
    .click()
    .session 
    .findById('stagePanel')
    .then(function(element) {
        element.findByClassName('itemList')
        .then(function(element) {
            element.getComputedStyle('display')
            .then(function (display) {
                // check display property
            });
        });

    });
```

I'm sure I'm doing many things wrong, so any and all advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this.remote` object is a [Command](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html) object, not a [Session](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Session.html) or [Element](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Element.html) object. If you want a Session you can get it from `this.remote.session` but it’s not normally necessary, and the Session object is not chainable.

The reason why your second `findById` is not working is because you aren’t [`end`ing](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#end) filtering you added with your previous `findBy` calls. When you don’t call `end` after a find operation, any subsequent find operation will use the element(s) from the previous find as the root elements to search in.

In other words, when you run `this.remote.findById('a').findById('b')`, it will search for element 'b' inside of element 'a', not inside the whole document `this.remote.findById('a').end().findById('b')` would search for both 'a' and 'b' inside the whole document.

Also, any time you perform an asynchronous operation from within a callback you need to `return` the result of the operation. If you don’t, the test won’t know that it needs to wait for more operations to complete. return chaining also prevents [callback pyramids](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/11/28/the-pyramid-of-doom-a-javascript-style-trap/):

```js
return this.remote
    .findById('buttonContainer')
      .findByClassName('buttonClass')
        .click()
        .end(2)
    .findById('stagePanel')
    .then(function(stagePanel) {
        return stagePanel.findByClassName('itemList');
    }).then(function(itemList) {
        return itemList.getComputedStyle('display');
    }).then(function (display) {
        // check display property
    });
```